# How can I crop an image in android with custom cropping layout?

Tags: android, image, android-activity, crop

I have an activity where I get an image and display it full screen, I want to draw a rectangle 600 x 600 for example over the image, I want the image to be darker and inside this rectangle to be bright 100% , and with my finger to change this rectangle's position (following my finger) and when iI click a button to be able to crop the image , to get only what it is inside this rectangle (bright area), how can I create this ?

Comment: There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Perhaps one already does what you want.

Comment: thanks for support i'll be checking them out !

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the coordinates in an arraylist and draw a clipPath line in ActionMove of onTouchListener

```
clipPath = new Path();
clipPath.moveTo(tdownx,tdowny);
for(int i = 0; i<your_array_list.size();i++){
clipPath.lineTo(your_array_list.get(i).getY(),your_array_list.get(i).getX( ));
 }
canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
```

You can see the output at [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_Foj2VQ6GU)